# Print function in a foreach loop : my scalar and text does not print

Tags: perl, output

This is a extract from my code :

```
foreach my $nouveau_code (@tableau_codes_utilises) {
        my $code_found = 0;
        foreach my $ligne_code_prospect (@tableau_liste_codes_prospects) {
                //SOME CODE
        }
        print "HERE IS $nouveau_code\n";
        if ( $code_found == 0 ) {
                print "le code $nouveau_code n'a pas été trouvé\n";
                STDOUT->autoflush;
        }
}
```

And the result of an iteration where `$code_found` is equal to 0 is (code is hidden here, but is alphanumeric) :

> HERE IS PAR****
>
> n'a pas été trouvé

I do not understand why the second print (in the if sequence) does not print the whole line. I guess there is a buffering problem but I cannot find what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to check - how do you know $code_found is 0?

Comment: subtle problem, I think Disco has the key

Comment: At a guess, `$nouveau_code` has come from a file that originated on a WIndows system and you are processing it on Linux?

Comment: @Disco3 i use another print flag in my test, but i removed it there to clean the code

Comment: `STDOUT->autoflush` does not flush the standard output buffer. `autoflush` just sets the flushing behavior of `print`/`printf` statements, and there's no point calling it inside a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up, i was trying some things in order to get my problem solved ;)

Comment: @Pechou: To flush a file handle it's just `flush STDOUT`. `flush` is a method from [`IO::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Handle.pm), but there is no need to `use` it explicitly as [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/File.pm) is loaded automatically if any of the filehandle operators are called. `IO::File` subclasses `IO::Handle` so `flush` is loaded implicitly. There is also `printflush`, which is the same as a call to `print` to a file handle followed by a `flush` of the handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, `$nouveau_code` has come from a file that originated on a Windows system and you are processing it on Linux?

If you use `chomp` in such a circumstance then it will remove the trailing newline, but not the carriage return, and printing the value will reset the screen cursor to the beginning of the line before printing anything else

The simple fix is to replace `chomp` with `s/\R//`, which will remove the CR as well as the LF on the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is happening here is that your second data item contains backspaces (BS) or a carriage return (CR).  So

1. your first item runs and `print`s out the first time, but since `code_found=1` it doesn't go into the `if`.
2. your second item runs and the CR or BS in the data obscure the fact that the `HERE IS` was printed
3. your second item does not have a code found so the second `print` happens and the first part of it is overwritten by the same CR or BS sequence in your variable

The easy way to confirm this is to redirect your output and look at it like so:

```
script > check.log
vim check.log
```

and you should see the extra data in there.  `less` would work fine in place of `vim` also.